# Ms access 2010 two SQL queries in FROM clause with an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join

I have this SQL request which should merge the results of the two subqueries with the `INNER JOIN`, but I get an error and I don't know why. Could you help me please?

```
SELECT 
      dateT, PC.id_serie
FROM (
      SELECT id_serie, MIN(dateF) as dateF FROM fixings GROUP BY id_serie
) AS PC1
INNER JOIN
(
      SELECT target_calendar.dateT, series.id_serie FROM target_calendar, series  LEFT JOIN fixings ON (PC.DateT=fixings.dateF) AND (PC.id_serie = fixings.id_serie)
) AS PC
ON
      PC1.dateF = PC.dateT
AND 
      (((pc1.[dateF]) Is Null))
AND 
      DateT <= Date();
```

Error : Circular reference caused by the alias "DateF"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the answer was to add more '(' and to not put the alias `AS dateF` as Gordon linoff suggested (it causes a circular reference).

Here you've the final SQL query :

```
SELECT 
          dateT, PC.id_serie
    FROM (
          SELECT id_serie, MIN(dateF) FROM fixings GROUP BY id_serie
    ) AS PC1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        (
          SELECT target_calendar.dateT, series.id_serie FROM target_calendar, series
         ) AS PC LEFT JOIN fixings ON (PC.DateT=fixings.dateF) AND (PC.id_serie = fixings.id_serie) 
   )
 ON
  (
         PC1.dateF = PC.dateT
  )
    WHERE 
         fixings.dateF Is Null
    AND 
          DateT <= Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that you don't define `PC1.DateF`.  You also has `fixings.DateF` in the `where` clause, but no table alias called `fixings` at that scope.  You need a column alias in the first subquery:

```
SELECT 
      dateT, PC.id_serie
FROM (
      SELECT id_serie, MIN(dateF) as dateF FROM fixings GROUP BY id_serie
) AS PC1
INNER JOIN
(
      SELECT target_calendar.dateT, series.id_serie FROM target_calendar, series  LEFT JOIN fixings ON (PC.DateT=fixings.dateF) AND (PC.id_serie = fixings.id_serie)
) AS PC
ON
      PC1.dateF = PC.dateT
AND 
      (((pc1.[dateF]) Is Null))
AND 
      DateT <= Date();
```

You are also mixing old-style joins and new-style joins in the `from` clause in the second subquery.  These should all be new-style joins.

Comment: Same result : Syntaxe error in JOIN operation. Then he selects `FROM fixings` in the first sub query

Comment: @Yumino . . . I got that on re-reading, so the problem is noted.

Comment: Another error appeared : Join expression not supported. Then he selects `(((PC1.[dateF]) Is Null))`. Even with the same `JOIN` style